# Simplest way to calculate the width and height of a jpeg image in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing

How can I calculate the width and height of an image in Python?
I'm using the "Image" library already if that makes it easier.

Thanks.

Comment: `Image` meaning PIL I assume? http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm

Answer (score 5):

```
im=Image.open(pic) 
print im.size
```

Comment: Easy enough.  Thanks for the fast response!